# How to change a range of numbers from one point to another using Vue Range Slider

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, range

I am using [npm package vue-custom-range-slider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-custom-range-slider)
but i have one problem my slider is divided into four colors blue, green, yellow, red it looks like this

[image]

Minimum number **19** and maximum number **65**

Imagine that a person can choose a certain age blue color is a range from **19** to **21** green **22** to **30** yellow **31** to **49** and the last red is above **50** for a more understandable example you can see this picture

[image]

I used a linear-gradient to split the slider into four slider colors, Now let me explain the problem.

I need to make the numbers for the blue range, that is, the numbers from **19** to **21** are inside the blue, **22** - **30** are inside the green **31-49** are inside the yellow, and above **50** are inside the red

Because at the moment the numbers are set incorrectly at the moment, for example, the numbers for blue are set from **19** to **30** and so on with all

I recommend looking at this [code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-butterfly-d00es) for a better understanding.

```
<template>
      <div class="slider-container">
        <custom-slider
          v-model="value"
          class="slider-containers"
          min="19"
          max="65"
          step="1"
        />
      </div>
</template>

<script>
import CustomSlider from "vue-custom-range-slider";
import "vue-custom-range-slider/dist/vue-custom-range-slider.css";

export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    CustomSlider,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: "0",
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
$slider-track-background: linear-gradient(
  to right,
  #b9e3e2 25%,
  #bbf680 25%,
  #bbf680 50%,
  #ffe500 50%,
  #ffe500 75%,
  #e5809e 75%,
  #e5809e 100%
) !default;
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the rage to percentages:

```
#b9e3e2 6.52173913%, //22
#bbf680 6.52173913%, 
#bbf680 26.08695652%, // 31
#ffe500 26.08695652%,
#ffe500 67.39130435%, // 50
#e5809e 67.39130435%,
#e5809e 100%
```

or even like this, if you want the color to change in between ages.

```
#b9e3e2 5.434782609%, // 21.5
#bbf680 5.434782609%,
#bbf680 25%, // 30.5
#ffe500 25%,
#ffe500 66.30434783%, // 49.5
#e5809e 66.30434783%,
#e5809e 100%
```